Clarifying the default "standard error" for error bars in Microsoft Excel/Powerpoint plots (calculated without N or SD)
I have noticed that Excel allows you to toggle "error bars" for any given plot and one of the options is to have the error bars denote standard errors. This is peculiar since if you do a barplot with two means in Excel or Powerpoint, there is no information about the standard deviation of each group and the N within each group which is required to estimate the standard error.
This link depicts what the standard error is for Excel/Powerpoint plots:
https://support.microsoft.
com/en-us/office/add-change-or-remove-error-bars-in-a-chart-e6d12c87-8533-4cd6-a3f5-864049a145f0
It appears as follows:

where,

s = series number
I = point number in series s
m = number of series for point y in chart
n = number of points in each series
y is = data value of series s and the I th point
n y = total number of data values in all series

To me, this reads as depicting the square roots of the average squared values in the plot.
Meanwhile, the actual standard error formula is the following:

which denotes the standard deviation divided by the square root of N (sample size).
To me, the formula for Excel's standard error appears quite different from standard error since it omits any information about variance/SD as well as sample size and only includes info about the values in a plot (which are likely means) and the number of those values.
I was wondering if...

... I am interpreting the Microsoft Excel/Powerpoint version of standard error correctly?
... Is this standard error estimate from Excel/Powerpoint misleading? Is there any way in which this approximates standard error despite omitting information about SD and N? Why might Microsoft have arrived at this different estimate of SE, and called it SE?


TBH, I did not dig deeply into this issue. But Excel used to be so well known for botching the most elementary statistics for multiple years and versions after the errors were first pointed out (see McCullough's papers from a few years back) that I would still absolutely not use it in any use case where precision is important. Interpret any Excel error bars as artificial flavoring, and use R or pretty much anything else in contexts where people might actually need to understand them.

Oh I agree. I was just trying to see if there was any validity to what they were doing here with error bars & standard errors or if it was truly completely misleading and wrong. And if it is, completely misleading, I figured a Stack Overflow / Cross Validated post highlighting that could be good to share

Excel is not doing what the documentation says, but I am not sure what it does is quite right either.
Suppose you had the data with $10$ observations
x    y
1   11
1   12
1   13
1   14
1   15
2   31 
2   32
3   71
3   72
3   73

Where the standard deviation (square the difference from the mean, divide by $n-1$, and take the square root) for the $x$ values is about $0.92$ and for the $y$ values is about $27.0$.  Plot the data as a scatter plot and ask Excel to give error bars based on standard deviation and you get

where it seems each bar (horizontal for $x$ and vertical for $y$) is centred on $(\bar x,y_i)$ or $(x_j,\bar y)$ and extends $1$ standard deviation in each direction.  It looks very strange.
The calculated standard error of the mean is then this divided by $\sqrt{n}$ so the documentation should have said $\dfrac{\sum \sum (y_{is}-\bar y)^2}{\sqrt{(n_y-1)(n_y)}}$.  The standard errors here are then about $0.29$ and $8.5$.  Plotting the data and asking Excel to give error bars based on standard error gives

where the bars are now centred on $(x_i,y_i)$ and extend $1$ standard error of the mean in each direction.  This is not as bad as the first, but it is still unclear to me what it is trying to show.
